# Access static member of template class

Tags: c++

I just want to access the static member of a template class. I know there are many posts here on how to initialize it, but my problem is printing its value.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class X
{
    static int i;
};

//There are answers everywhere on this site to initialize it

template<typename T>
int X<T>::i = 5;

//But Please help me to access it    
int main()
{
    X<int> x;
//Problem below I just want to access it
    cout << endl << X<int>::i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot about `public` keyword.

Comment: static members need not have specifier.

Comment: @Robust Werch ein Illtum!

Comment: You forgot to post the error message, but Baum did it for you ;)

Answer (score 4):

Another case where the compiler error message contains the answer. E.g. gcc says

> main.cpp:13:5: error: 'int X::i' is private

and of course you cannot access `private` fields from outside the class. Make it `public` instead.